# RVIZ 2 ROS2 Cant See Any Joints

Tags: ros, ros2, rviz, urdf

Although I got the visuals for my joints in my code(two wheels at the side and one at the bottom) I can not see them on the rviz2 visuals -in gazebo I have no problems I can see the whole robot. I have the joint-state-publisher and joint-state-publisher-gui installed and running throught the whole process. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and ros-foxy.

```
    <joint name="left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="left_wheel"/>
        <origin xyz="0 ${wheel_offset_y} 0" rpy="-${pi/2} 0 0" />
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="left_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_thickness}"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="blue"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <sphere radius="${wheel_radius}"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="${wheel_mass}" length="${wheel_thickness}" radius="${wheel_radius}">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
    </link>

    <gazebo reference="left_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>


    </gazebo>




    <!-- RIGHT WHEEL LINK -->

    <joint name="right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="right_wheel"/>
        <origin xyz="0 ${-wheel_offset_y} 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0" />
        <axis xyz="0 0 -1"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="right_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_thickness}"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="blue"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <sphere radius="${wheel_radius}"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="${wheel_mass}" length="${wheel_thickness}" radius="${wheel_radius}">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
    </link>

    <gazebo reference="right_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
    </gazebo>


    <!-- CASTER WHEEL LINK -->

    <joint name="caster_wheel_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="chassis"/>
        <child link="caster_wheel"/>
        <origin xyz="${caster_wheel_offset_x} 0 ${caster_wheel_offset_z}"/>
    </joint>


    <link name="caster_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <sphere radius="${caster_wheel_radius}"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="white"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <sphere radius="${caster_wheel_radius}"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_sphere mass="${caster_wheel_mass}" radius="${caster_wheel_radius}">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_sphere>
    </link>

    <gazebo reference="caster_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/White</material>
        <mu1 value="0.001"/>
        <mu2 value="0.001"/>
    </gazebo>

</robot>
```

[joint state publisher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5quS.png)
[Rviz2, as you can see no wheels that can be seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoexX.png)

I have installed the joint-state-publisher packages new, didn't worked out

Comment: Might be better to ask this on robotics.stackexchange.com.